# How to parse ld+json using python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, json-ld

I've been trying some webscraping and I came across some interesting data located inside this tag:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
```

I've been able to isolate that tag using beautiful soup

```
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

p = soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'})
print p
```

but I haven't been able to work with the data or to extract any data from that tag.

If I try to use regex to get some stuff out of it I get:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How can I get the data from that script tag and use it like I'd use a dictionary or a string? I'm using python 2.7 by the way.

Answer (score 11):

You should read the JSON with `json.loads` to convert it into a dictionary.

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_ld_json(url: str) -> dict:
    parser = "html.parser"
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, parser)
    return json.loads("".join(soup.find("script", {"type":"application/ld+json"}).contents))
```

The `join` / `contents` combination removes the script tags.

Answer (score 6):

you should read the html to parse

```
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
p = soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'})
print p.contents
```

Comment: I get an error saying from the "html/read()")
It says this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    get_price()
  File "test.py", line 16, in get_price
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.read()")
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: html.read(). Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: if you need you can use lxml instead

Comment: @wessells if require only text inside it use print p.find(text=True)

Answer (score 0):

The comments above didn't help (thanks though)

In the end I used:

```
p = str(soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'}))
```

I forced it into a string which isn't really pretty, but it did the job. I know there's probably a better way out there, but this worked for me.